# How to get values from an array of promises?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, promise, request-promise

```
for (var year = year_from; year <= year_to; year++) {
  for (var month = month_from; month <= 12; month++) {
    for (var day = day_from; day <= 31; day++) {
      var url = "something_url" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/";
      var current_date = day + "." + month + "." + year;
      try {
        var options = {
          uri: url,
          transform: function (body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('div[class="post"]').each(function (month, elem) {
              var nested = $(this).find('div[class="text"]');
              var nested_a = nested.find('a');
              var nested_href = nested_a.attr('href');
              var nested_text = nested_a.text();
              var lc_nested_text = nested_text.toLowerCase();
              var s_lc_nested_text = lc_nested_text.toString();
              if (s_lc_nested_text.indexOf(query1) > -1) {
                post.name1 = s_lc_nested_text;
                post.url1 = f_url + nested_href;
                post.date1 = current_date;
              }
            });
          }
        };

        prs.push(rp(options));
      }
      catch {
        console.log('parse error');
      }
    }
  }
}

Promise.all(prs)
  .then((result) => {
    res.send(result);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I get the result from the request to the API with request-promise and put it in an array of promises. After I send this result to the browser and there I get the following:

[image: Browser Response]

Comment: @Ramesh, on the last line

Comment: What is in `rp()`? Also, I strongly suggest you use momentjs instead of doing `days <= 31`. Check [this](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/10-days-in-month/)

Comment: Can you prove that the problem isn't merely that `rp()` is returning null?

Comment: Why don't you try printing the result in console before sending it as a response? Let's see if you're actually getting any values

Comment: I guess you should definitely use `RxJS` (https://rxjs.dev/) for managing arrays of promises. Especially if you are using `request-promise` in your code.

Comment: Because I print this in console on the client

Comment: This is the code for Node.js. rp is 'request-promise' (var rp = require('request-promise');)

Comment: Your `transform` function doesn't return anything. Try hardcode `return 1` and check result